# Android Studio: create another activity (package name is not set to a valid package name)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

My android application has a package `spectorsky` placed directly in `java1` catalog. Incide this package, there is launched activity `MainActivity`, and I need to create additional activity in the same package.

However when I call `New activity` dialog and type `spectorky` as a package name, error `package name is not set to a valid package name` appears.

Dialog suggests `com.tmp.spectorsky.calendar` as a package name (`calendar` is a name of the app), but this creates some directories and places new activity in a new created package.

[image: Dialog for creating empty activity]

So, the question: **how to create new activity in the same package?**

Thanks for any idea

Comment: Your android view screen shot please?

Comment: majuran, printscreen added.

Comment: You have a small mistake here. with this mistake you can not be able to build. what is your applicationId inside app level gradle file?

Comment: majuran. thanks for a quick reply. It doesn't reach to build, it is impossible even create additional activity in the same package. In fact, I went around the problem - created activity in the suggested  package, and then moved it to my package.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: majuran,  I've gone around the problem - created activity in the suggested package, and then moved it to my package. It works, but I wouldn't call it solution.

Comment: Aah... Ok ok... You need to move whole files to under application id

Answer (score 0):

Your activity package name should start with your project package name. your activity package must present in your project package.
[image: Like this]
1st change your view from project to android [image: change your view from project to android]
if you want to create your own package then right-click on the 1st package name then choose to create the package. After that right-click on your package name then create activity.

Comment: Partha Hudati, thanks for an answer. In my case, there is package `spectorsky`, and I'd like to create two activities within this package. Why `Configure Activity` dialog doesn't permit it? Maybe, package name must contain  (or even start) with `com.` level...